# setSelection not changing ListView position

Tags: android, listview, orientation

I am having some trouble with the ListView setSelection method. I am attempting to have my list view remain at the same index when switching between landscape and portrait orientation. However, every time I rotate and the activity is recreated, the listview starts at the top. The code I am using is as follows:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ArrayList<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (Integer i : f_checkedMessages) {
        indices.add(i);
    }
    savedInstanceState.putIntegerArrayList("CheckedMessageIndices", indices);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("ListIndex", f_listView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ArrayList<Integer> indices = savedInstanceState.getIntegerArrayList("CheckedMessageIndices");
    for (Integer i : indices) {
        f_checkedMessages.add(i);
    }
    int listIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt("ListIndex");
    f_listView.setSelection(listIndex);
}
```

I have used the debugger to verify that listIndex is the correct value. It should also be mentioned that the checked listview items persist when changing orientation. I know that setSelected only SELECTS the listview item if in touch mode, but the documentation says that this method will align the listview regardless of whether in touch mode or not.

Does anyone know why this is not working or if there is a better way of going about this?

Thanks, your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 34):

If further help, after a few hours lost with this problem, I managed to solve it using the same example of A-IV, with some modifications.

First of all, it is essential that the method clearFocus() is called before execute the runnable.

Devices that have just as touch mode controller has no visual effect when the method setSelection(index) is called, but the item will normally be selected. Therefore, it is necessary to call requestFocusFromTouch() to enable visual changes caused by the method setSelection(index).

After calling the setSelection(index), call the requestFocus() so that to give focus to view.

```
@Override public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
final int listIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt("ListIndex");
f_listView.clearFocus();
f_listView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        listView.requestFocusFromTouch();
        listView.setSelection(listIndex);
        listView.requestFocus();
    }
});
```

}

I hope I helped!

Comment: The view to give focus to on the last line of `run()` might be some other view, not necessarily the same `ListView` you selected, I think. Anyway, that's what I needed to do, and seems to work. Thank you. Still, it sounds quite strange that to have a list scroll to a specific element one must directly fiddle with focus. I would classify this as yet another unfortunate design decision in Android, but that's probably just out of frustration grown by dealing with it.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks. But it annoys me that calls that should be straightforward, like list.setSelection(x) don't work as expected at all and it's not well documented that there are steps you have to take before calling it. Aghh... What's the purpose of making a function that works like this and why not inclide requestFocus inside it...

Comment: This worked for me, but the ListView item highlights as if the user was holding their finger down on the specified ListView item and as soon as I touch the screen the item is no longer selected (highlighted). Any solutions so that the selection is set by a finger tap and not a hold?

Answer (score 8):

You can use below code for solve this problem

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    listView = getListView();
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    
    listView.post(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            listView.setSelection(position);
        }
    });
}
```

OR

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setSelection(position);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

OR Please refer following link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/514527/ListActivity-setSelection-within-onCreate

Answer (score 7):

You can't set selection directly after data has been changed. Try this:

```
@Override public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    final int listIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt("ListIndex");
    f_listView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            listView.setSelection(listIndex);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Here is related thread: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/127ca57414035301?pli=1

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should use "smoothScrollToPosition(int position)" if you are in the SDK level >= 8.

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me was that i call 
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
after calling 
mListView.setSelection(0);

now i am calling in this order:

```
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 mListView.setSelection(0);
```

and it's working.

Comment: and this is relevant to this question how?

Answer (score 0):

If your ListView is inside a ListFragment, just call [setSelection()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#setSelection%28int%29).

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me was:

```
    mListView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mListView.setSelection(index);
        }
    }, 300);
```

Looks awful, but this way it works in both touch and non-touch modes.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the best solution without using post a Runnable:

```
list.setAdapter(adapter);
list.setSelection(list.getCount() - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code,

```
sp2.setAdapter(sp2.getAdapter());
        sp2.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        sp2.setSelection(0, false);
```